# Ошибка предварительного объявления

Tags: c++, qt

Есть два окна.

mainwindow.h:

```
#include "algorithmdialog.h"
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AlgorithmDialog* algDialog;
...
};
```

algorithmdialog.h:

```
class MainWindow;
// class MainWindow : public QMainWindow;

class AlgorithmDialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    MainWindow * mainWindow;
...
}
```

При компиляции дает ошибки

```
algorithmdialog.cpp:58: ошибка: invalid use of incomplete type 'class MainWindow'
algorithmdialog.h:15: ошибка: forward declaration of 'class MainWindow'
```

Вроде все указано правильно, с закоменченным вариантом тоже не собирается, полазил по форумам, не нашел нужных решений, думаю все дело в том, что второй файл подключается в первый, как решить  проблему? И в чем она состоит?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Для добавления нового класса окна используйте встроенный визард и проблем у вас не будет. на лицо сразу видно что не хватает макроса  Q_OBJECT

Comment: в "algorithmdialog.h" строка "class MainWindow;" без "{ }" это нормально ?

Comment: MainWindow без {} это нормально, потому так то когда он дойдет до реального его объявления не будет redefenition error,   Q_OBJECT прописан в обоих классах, я просто это не стал сюда добавлять, оба окна добавлены через мастера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В обоих заголовочных надо вставить предварительную декларацию друг на друга, а в файлах реализации указать заголовочные.

Comment: Вот верный ответ, только я его дополню, помимо самих классов в qt есть тот же класс объявленный в namespace Ui, в algorithms.cpp надо подключать файл "ui_mainwindow.h", если нужно иметь доступ к виджетам главного окна, а мне надо было. хоить и пришлось сделать ui в public.

Comment: Вот только непонятно почему в cpp файле он не реагирует если подулючен mainwondow.h в который уже подключен ui_mainwondow.h

Comment: Если ui_mainwindow.h подключен в mainwindow.h, то подключения ui_mainwindow.h в файле реализации диалога по идее не требуется. Просто по умолчанию файлы "ui_*" обычно располагаются в *.cpp, а в *.h указывают только предварительную декларацию. В этом случае - да, потребуется подключить ui в файл реализации диалога.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное дело в тех строках которые автор не приводит ... т.е.

> algorithmdialog.cpp:58 и algorithmdialog.h:15

Два класса пустых класса с содержимым
MainWindow.h:

```
#include <QDialog>

class MainWindow;

class AlgorithmDialog : public QDialog {
 Q_OBJECT
 public:
  MainWindow * mainWindow;
};
```

и AlgorithmDialog.h:

```
#include <QMainWindow>

class AlgorithmDialog;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
 Q_OBJECT
 public:
  AlgorithmDialog* algDialog;
};
```

у меня прекрасно компилируются. Так что дело не в объявлении классов, а в том что с ними дальше делается в коде.

Если в тех строках идет обращение к методам (или переменным) класса через указатель, то соответсвенно надо включить хэдэр от нужного для использования класса.
Т.е. начало файла AlgorithmDialog.cpp будет таким:

```
#include "AlgorithmDialog.h"
#include "MainWindow.h"
```

а начало файла MainWindow.cpp будет таким:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "AlgorithmDialog.h"
```

Вроде если по логике вещей все делать то прекрасно все срастается.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще странно как-то выглядит у тебя, просто попробуй в algorithmdialog.h поключить mainwindow.h как обычно:

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED
#define MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED

#include "algorithmdialog.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    AlgorithmDialog* algDialog;
...
};


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED
```

algorithmdialog.h:

```
#ifndef ALGORITHMDIALOG_H_INCLUDED
#define ALGORITHMDIALOG_H_INCLUDED

#include "mainwindow.h"

class AlgorithmDialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    MainWindow * mainWindow;
...
}

#endif // ALGORITHMDIALOG_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: пробовал уже, не выходит, вообще подключать один файл в другой, в который уже подключен первый  плохая идея.

Comment: с каких это пор это плохая идея? для этого как раз и 
    
    #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED
    #define MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H_INCLUDED

Comment: и да, какую ошибку выдает при варианте подключения их друг в друга?

Comment: я знаю про #ifndef #define #endif, дело совсем не в них,  algorithmdialog.h:22: ошибка: 'MainWindow' does not name a type  algorithmdialog.h:23: ошибка: 'MainWindow' has not been declared  Очевидно что сборщик подключив один файл, не доайдя до объявления класса, натунклся там на подключение другого файла, в котором наткнулся повторное подключение mainwindiw увидел константу и прыгнул в endif, mainwindow остался необъявленным, это не работающий метод.

Comment: а не забыл #include "algorithmdialog.h" и #include "mainwindow.h"? я сначала их забыл написать) а так вроде все работает